# Pylint failing with 10/10 for duplicate code messages

Tags: gitlab-ci, pylint, code-duplication, pylintrc

I'm having an issue with Pylint. In our project, we have several tests set up that have the same exceptions. Pylint is reading these as duplicate code (I'm getting the "Similar lines in * files" message), but the problem is that it isn't reducing the score of our code based on these. Moreover, linting passes locally but fails on GitLab (using the same linting script), and the score is 10/10 in both instances. I checked this with 'duplicate-code' enabled and disabled in .pylintrc with the same results. I'm using the default scoring, which includes refactoring.

Any idea what could be happening here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's probably a difference in the environment between gitlab and locally. The other issues look like a bug in pylint. Duplicate code is a slow check because there is a lot of comparison to do on everything against everything and the multiprocessing is not ready yet. If you're using multiple jobs, try removing the ``-j`` option first.